# .NET Reflector local variable values not available on breakpoints

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reflector

I'm using the .NET Reflector VS extension v. 9.0.1.374 in VS 2015.  I'm debugging a third party dll being used by my web app running in IIS Express.  I can hit breakpoints and step through code but I cannot see any local variable values. In the Watch window I see "The name 'abc' does not exist in the current context" when I add a watch to an in-scope variable. I also cannot step into code I've decompiled.

Comment: Release build? The variable may have been optimized away

Comment: If that would cause the behavior it must be.